# Analyzing posts on Facebook

Tags: comments

I want to figure out a way who have talked {view, like and comments) about a specific post on our Facebook's fan page. we want to examine the influence of the daily activities of fans on the timing and amount of a specific post. Influencers and the occurrence time of every "like" or "comment" should be collected. Is there any tool for modeling and clustering of post's data? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible. I know this is not the forum to advertise a specific product, but I literally wrote this exact thing over the last couple months for our company. Check it out http://napkinlabs.com/apps/ it is called SuperFans.